# Stored procedure using JSON values not iterating through object array values in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, stored-procedures

I'm pretty new to java and JSON as a whole and am having an issue getting this scenario to work. Here we go:

I have to send a JSON file that will trigger 2 stored procedures. The first SP will write to a header table, while the other uses a cursor value returned by the first SP to write to a detail table any number of times.

I'm defining my JSON file as follows, which can have any number of detail object arrays (for practical purposes I'm just testing with 2).

My header SP writes correctly and returns the cursor value I'll need to write to my details table. The problem is with my detail SP, which is only writting the values of the first array, ignoring the second one. In other words, the code is not iterating through all the array values defined.

Also, my StackTrace is giving me both:

- DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
- java.sql.SQLException: Cursor state not valid

How can I write the FOR clause correctly so that it iterates through all my detail object array values?

Thank you for your time!

---

POJO DEFINITION:

HeaderPOJO:

private String company;

private String name;

private List detail;

DetailPOJO:

private String company;

private String group;

private int id;

---

JSON SENT:
{

```
"company":"1",
"name":"somedude",
"detail":[
      {
        "company":"1",
        "group":"AB",
        "id":1
      },
      {
        "company":"1",
        "group":"AC",
        "id":2          
      }

     ]
```

}

---

SNIPPET OF JAVA CODE:

public int dostuff(@RequestBody dostuff savestuffH)
{

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Connection con = null;

int cursorreturned = 0;

try
{
    java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver (new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver ());
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("WORKING CONNECTION");            
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("call stored.procedure1(HEADER PARAMETERS)");

    while(rs.next())
            {
                cursorreturned = rs.getInt("SP Cursor"); //THIS IS A VALUE RETURNED BY MY SP WHICH I NEED FOR MY DETAILS TABLE
            }

    for(DetailPOJO savestuffD:savestuffH.getDetail())
            {
                rs = st.executeQuery("call stored.procedure2('" + savestuffD.getCompany() + "', " + cursorreturned + ", '" + savestuffD.getGroup() + "', " + savestuffD.getid() + ")");
            }
}
```

}

Comment: To call a stored procedure, you need to use [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), not `Statement`.